# Character encoding issue when importing articles description into magento

Tags: import, importexport

I put all articles in a csv file with swedish characters `åäö` and thai characters `กขค` and some other characters like `é`.

Saved it in excel Apple OSX csv. Opened Textwrangler and replaced all `;` with `,` 
Sets character encoding to `Unicode (UTF-8)` and `Windows CRLF`.

Magento displays wildcard character `�` for the swedish characters.
Not sure what character encoding or how I should save it so that magento will be able to display properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try opening the file in open office.  Excel sucks when it comes to character encoding and even cvs format in general.  Mac edition is even worse.

It's also free:
https://www.openoffice.org

Comment: I don't believe in downloading other software to resolve an issue. But thanks for advice.

Comment: So the software tools you use are not working, but you don't want to download other software tools?  Okay man, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to add encoding to a web page. Since it seems you have tried a few, i think you can try AddCharset UTF-8 in your .htaccess. 
Also, if the problem persist you might want to try [this](http://www.pds-host.co.uk/blog/?p=10)